# When pressed, why is ^C echoed out in xterm but not ^Z

Tags: terminal, xterm

I'm remapping my keys in xterm in my `.Xresources file`.

Here is a sample:

```
Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <KeyPress> A: string("^[J0A")
```

My question is why does the string `0A` get printed out to the terminal when the bind is pressed (Just like when pressing `^C`)?

And why do certain default binds like `^Z` not get printed to the screen?


Also is there a way to explicitly state in the `.Xresources` file that you do not want that key printed out to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

All the [**`string`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:string) action does in **`translations`** is specify some data that is sent to the terminal for the given key-combination.  The terminal (actually what's running inside the terminal such as a shell or an editor) determines what's *echoed*.

If you want a key to do something different, there are other *actions* that you could use than [**`string`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:string).

Comment: Hahah this is a hilarious coincidence. I just sent you an email about an hour or so ago. I looked through the whole manual and I couldn't find a suitable action/method, or I skimmed over it without knowing. Which action would you recommend? All I want is the same functionality that `string` offers but without the echo. Or do I have to go deeper and configure the terminal within the terminal settings?

Comment: The latter - other actions tell xterm to do various things.  When you send data, the application inside the terminal controls each using termios calls or stty commands.

Comment: Well it looks like the solution I've come up with is just to use deeper escape sequences. Such as: `Ctrl  ~Meta  ~Shift <KeyPress> A: string("^[J^[0^[A")` This shouldn't break anything, right?